# Artifact in bamboo

Tags: .net, bitbucket, bamboo, artifact

I want to ask you one question. I'm trying to do artifact in bamboo but when I build a project with trigger in logs about artifacts I have this one - "Unable to publish artifact" and I don't know what I need to do. When I create artifact in location I'm write folder with project name where project is and in copy pattern something like this **/*.*

Eventually I need to build project after commit and put this project with artifact on server where I can check changes but I have problem with last step.

Someone can tell me what am doing wrong? This is build for .NET solution.

Comment: ref, need finish this in job :(

Answer (score 0):

When you specify an artifact in Bamboo, you reference it from bamboo's build directory. For example, if you project's directory structure (as pulled from your repo) looks like this:

```
projectname/
   folder1/
      subfolder1/
   folder2/
      subfolder2/
```

If you want to create an artifact out of the entire project you would use `./` as your starting location and to copy everything under it you would use this glob `/**/*`

As another example, if you wanted to create an artifact from subfolder2 the location could be `./` and the glob would be `projectname/folder2/subfolder2/**/*`